# wordpress mod-rewrite for single non-ssl url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a seemingly simple redirection problem, but can't find the correct re-write to get it to work.

For my WordPress site, I basically want all requests to go to https except for one page (/mitel2/) which needs to be served via http.

So in my .htaccess file, this works to redirect https requests on the page in question to http:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mitel2/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

As I say, the above works and requests to https://www.mysite.co.uk/mitel2/ are redirected to http://www.mysite.co.uk/mitel2/ - great!

So now I want to redirect all http requests that aren't /mitel2/ to https, so I change my code to this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mitel2/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mitel2/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

But now although my http requests are redirected to https, when I try to load my excluded page over ssl instead of redirecting to the http, it just redirects to the homepage and still over https!

I'm really not sure what's going on here, so any help that you guys can shed would be gratefully received!

Many thanks
Kevin

Comment: I think there is an automatic redirect in a lowest level that redirects user to homepage if he's not connecting over SSL.
Can you check if I'm right?

Comment: @Syncro I'm not sure, I don't think I've ever heard of that before